# Inserting value into MutableList

Tags: scala

I would like to insert a value into a specific index in a scala `MutableList` which will push successive elements one index along (much like the `java.util.List.add(index, element)` method). I tried using the `MutableList.add()` method and it compiled but annoyingly I got an `UnsupportedOperation` exception at runtime.

I wrote the below method (where `mList` is the `MutableList[String]` instance) but as you can see it requires a lot of what I deem unnecessary conversion steps. Is there a built-in/faster way of doing it?

```
def insert(idx: Int, element: String): Unit ={
    val newList = new scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String]()
    for(i <- 0 until idx) newList += mList(i)
    newList += element
    for(i <- idx until content.size) newList += mList(i)
    mList = newList
}
```

Psuedocode example:

```
mList = ["a", "f", "x", "e"]
insert(2, "z")
// mList is now ["a", "f", "z", "x", "e"]
```

I have seen answers on here that apply to immutable lists, but none that apply to mutable lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternative way of inserting an element in the mutable list:

```
val ls = MutableList(1,2,3,4) 

val pair = ls.splitAt(1) // split it at the appropriate index into two lists.

pair._1 ++ MutableList(20) ++ pair._2 // MutableList(1, 20, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to use a [ListBuffer](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/9483542b1304601683fbda0fee1eef1c8c10696a/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.scala#l167) which is mutable and has both constant time append and prepend operations. Converting to an immutable list is just a case of `lb.toList`.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way using the patch method to replace the current element at the specified index with a sequence containing the new element followed by the current element:

```
ls.patch(index, Seq(value, self(index)), 1)
```

I found it quite difficult to turn this into a reusable solution because the patch method takes an implicit argument in order to build the right type of collection and the builders for mutable and immutable sequences have different type signatures. This is what I have so far:

```
// --- insert(index, value) implementation.
// uses a RichSeq wrapper to decorate mutable and immutable sequences/lists with the insert(...) method.

import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.immutable.List
import scala.collection.immutable.List._
import scala.collection.{GenSeqLike, mutable}

object RichSeq {
  type MutableSeqType[A, +Repr] = GenSeqLike[A, Repr] with mutable.Builder[A, Repr]
  type ImmutableSeqType[+A, +Repr] = GenSeqLike[A, Repr]

  def apply[A, Repr](self: MutableSeqType[A, Repr]): RichMutableSeq[A, Repr] = new RichMutableSeq[A, Repr](self)
  def apply[A, Repr, Coll](self: ImmutableSeqType[A, Repr]): RichImmutableSeq[A, Repr] = new RichImmutableSeq[A, Repr](self)

  implicit def toRichSeq[A, Repr](self: MutableSeqType[A, Repr]): RichMutableSeq[A, Repr] = RichSeq(self)
  implicit def toRichSeq[A, Repr](self: ImmutableSeqType[A, Repr]): RichImmutableSeq[A, Repr] = RichSeq(self)
}

final class RichMutableSeq[A, Repr](val self: RichSeq.MutableSeqType[A, Repr]) {
  import RichSeq._
  def insert(index: Int, value: A)(implicit ev: CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, MutableSeqType[A, Repr]]): MutableSeqType[A, Repr] = self.patch(index, Seq(value, self(index)), 1)(ev)
}

final class RichImmutableSeq[A, Repr](val self: RichSeq.ImmutableSeqType[A, Repr]) {
  import RichSeq._
  def insert(index: Int, value: A)(implicit ev: CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, ImmutableSeqType[A, Repr]]): ImmutableSeqType[A, Repr] = self.patch(index, Seq(value, self(index)), 1)(ev)
}

// --- test object ---

object TestRichSeq {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import RichSeq._

    val ls0 = mutable.MutableList(1, 2, 3, 4)
    val ls1 = ls0.insert(1, 20)

    println(ls1)

    val ls2 = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
    val ls3 = ls2.insert(1, 20)

    println(ls3)
  }
}
```

Reusing [Samar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/568990/samar)'s test, the output from the test program is:

```
MutableList(1, 20, 2, 3, 4)
List(1, 20, 2, 3, 4)
```

The solution works for both mutable and immutable lists, but it seems to need more use of implicits than I'd like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will probably go with the accepted answer due to its simplicity :)